# Parameter 0 of constructor in one.business.Validation required a bean of type two.client.IRestClient' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constructor, javabeans

If I don't use @Component for the class the application is running, but I need to use @Component for the class.

I need to use a @Service class interface i.e IRestClient

Service class

```
@Service
public class RestClient implements IRestClient {
}
```

Component class

```
package one.business;

import two.client.IRestClient;

@Component
    public class Validation implements IRun<RunModel> {
        private IRestClient restClient;
    
       public Validation(final IRestClient restClient) {
            this.restClient= restClient;
        }
    }
```

If I run the application I'm getting below error.

> Parameter 0 of constructor in one.business.Validation required a bean
> of type two.client.IRestClient' that could not be found.

I tried by adding @Autowired also, but not working.

Comment: Make sure they are in packages that are scanned by Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes it is in package

Comment: Please include the package statements you have and add your Spring Boot appliation. I doubt they are else the error wouldn't occur.